# width 100% on an overflow scroll element in flex container

Tags: css

Because a picture is worth a thousand words, I'll show it first:

[image]

In red is my flex container, in blue is an element with a fixed width of 50px, in green is a section with a 100% width, in yellow is a list also with a 100% width and an overflow scroll, and finally in purple are my list elements width a fixed width of 100px.

I want the green element to fit in my red flex container. How can I do that?

Here's the codesandbox used to make the screenshot above (it's made in React but the html is in `App.js` and the css in `styles.css`):
https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-moon-0rsfc?file=/src/styles.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `overflow: hidden` to the green box to make it stay in the bounds of it's parent.

```css
section {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: green;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it did the trick, thanks. I'm struggling to understand why though, can you explain?

Comment: If you set the overflow property on the x axis to `overflow: hidden;`, it will only let the element expand to the width of its parent container and everything else extra will be cutoff.

Answer (score 2):

You had set widths that I removed. Also, I see that You may not need the `div` container.
I left it commented out in case you decide you want to keep the blue div.

```
main {
  height: 100px;
  padding: 5px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
}
/* 
div {
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
} */

section {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: purple;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 2px;
}
```

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood my issue. I need the exact same layout, the fixed width on the red container was to easily reproduce the issue,  the blue div is actually a real element that I need to keep.